# When I run this PHP code nothing prints to the screen

Tags: php, html, mysql

Any ideas why this doesn't list out the contents of my db? what i think id should do... is print out a list of the contents (is author, title, category, year and ISBN). but i get nothing. no error or anything.... even if i put a echo statement in there, nothing seems to print to the screen...

```
<?php // query.php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error()); 

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
echo 'Author' . mysql_result($result,$j,'author') . '<br />';
echo 'Title' . mysql_result($result,$j,'title') . '<br />';
echo 'Category' . mysql_result($result,$j,'category') . '<br />';
echo 'Year' . mysql_result($result,$j,'year') . '<br />';
echo 'ISBN' . mysql_result($result,$j,'isbn') . '<br />';
} 
?>
```

Comment: can you reduce the code to the minimum amount where your issue still shows up?

Comment: hmm. i wish i knew where the error was, but at this point im just sort of following the book blindly. ill see if i can find a shorter example.

Comment: white screen of death= error checking\display is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your latest revision:

**Problem #1:**
You should use some variant of `mysql_fetch_` in order to fetch the rows from the resource returned by [mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  Using `mysql_result` can be inefficient.  Usually, people use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php).  This will return an array, which you can then access using its key, which depends on which `mysql_fetch_` function you use.  For example, if you are trying to get a column named `'id'` for the current row, you want to retrieve that by using `'id'` as the key for your array.

**Problem #2:**
Your loop is wrong.
`for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$i)` should be `for ($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)`.  Note the `++$i` was changed to `++$j`.  Otherwise, you have an infinite loop (until the timeout is reached for PHP).

**Problem #3:**
`mysql_num_rows()` can return FALSE.
According to the documentation, the function will return the number of rows or FALSE on failure.  Although FALSE can be coerced into integer 0, I do not like to depend on this.

Also, if you purchased this book I hope you did not pay full price for it.  These `mysql_` methods have been deprecated.  Thus, it is more useful to use the [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extensions instead.

---

Based on your latest edit, you've fixed Problem #2.  Add a `var_dump($rows);` line **before* you enter your loop to double-check you have more than 0 lines.

Also, have you checked your error log?  Locate your error log and see if it's displaying errors on there instead of your browser.  That would explain why you would be seeing a white screen.

Comment: ty. i think all is well now. im still very new to the web languages, and databases.

Answer (score 0):

To join string variables in php you should do it like this:

```
$my_bigger_string="some string variable" . $my_string . "some more words";
```

Try applying that to all your strings and see what happens.

Comment: no change, still a blank browser.

Comment: I see missing brackets after ifs... and isn't there a missing semicolon on line 7?

Comment: Can you check your error log?  What setup are you using?